# accessing methods from anywhere in java

Tags: java

Lets say i have a manager class in a program. I want to be able to access the methods in that class from anywhere in the program, without having to make a new instance of the class each time. how does one do this in java?

Comment: public static..........

Comment: i have tried that multiple times but it seems you cant do that in java, please show me if this is not the case.

Comment: @PandTurlte Show us what have you done? Before you claim you cannot do this in Java, try to do some reading

Comment: @JunedAhsan public static class GM {

} modifier static not allowed here

Comment: @PandaTurtle `static` method.... not class..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the methods all public and static. Public makes them accessible by any other class and static means that the method can be called without having an instance of the class.

Ex.

```
public static void myMethod() {}
```